# Why use the dollar sign in Es6 class constructor

Tags: class, ecmascript-6, syntax, constructor, dollar-sign

I have seen the following code in a tutorial

```
export default class Model() {
    constructor() {
     this.$collection = [];

    }
}
```

My question is why did he use the dollar sign before the collection?

Comment: Can you point to the tutorial so we have some context?

Answer (score 0):

The $ is only a possible character in names of attributes and methods. For conventions it's used to identify attributes/methods which are private but this character not add any behavior to the attribute/variable.